# What does the symbol $\sqsubset$ mean? Is it the same as $\subset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have tried looking for this symbol but I found the definition for latter only. Hence, I have this doubt if these two are same. If not, can anyone please let me know the difference? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In view of the tag "notation", I do not understand the downvote.

Comment: @SuhasChikkanna Can you give an example of this symbol used in context?

Comment: $\sqsubset$ is sometimes used as $\subset$. However, there are also other, common uses. For example Jech uses $\sqsubseteq$ to denote subalgebras of a given Boolean algebra. So, in order to settle your question, you'd have to provide us with a source in which you encountered it.

Comment: @PatrickStevens 

I found this notation in a scientific paper called - "Subscription Subsumption Evaluation for Content-based Publish/Subscribe Systems"  in which I came across this, for instance a statement in that paper is as follows:- "   More succinctly, we denote this fact by “s ⊑ S iff s ⊂ C ”   " . Here is the link for the paper as well :- [link](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~hjafarpo/Files/MW08_CameraReady_1.pdf)

Comment: What is "this fact" that the authors are referring to? That should settle the matter.

Comment: @ceph 
I can say that they are talking in context of set theory itself. The "this" you pointed to is specifically subject related. But the symbols which I mentioned I am pretty sure they are talking in the context of set symbols or math notation only.

Comment: The meaning of $\sqsubseteq$ in this paper is defined in Definition 1 and no, it's not the same as $\subset$.

Comment: @Stefan
Yes I think you are right. These two symbols in this context(i.e., with reference to the paper I mentioned in link) have different meanings. But I am yet to conclude if the symbol "⊏" in general, would have a common meaning in other contexts or does it vary in each and every scenario with the context. I will update a conclusion on that asap.

Comment: It varies, all notation varies. Symbols have no inherent meaning - you can replace them at your will with any other symbol. But... you shouldn't, at least if you want humans to read your papers.

Comment: @Stefan
Yes, you are right. I think, I would like to mark your answer as correct. Thank you for all the guidance. Much appreciated!!.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help (:

Comment: Sometimes $\sqsubset$ is used to denote a partial ordering. Here's an example where $\sqsubseteq$ and $\leq$ denote two different partial orderings of the same set: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tileorder

Comment: @Stefan: So you say my notation of $1+3=9$ where $1$ means two, $+$ means times, "3" means six, $=$ means "less than" and $9$ means twenty, is a bad idea? ;-)

Comment: @celtschk Yeah, [probably](http://karagila.org/2016/syntactic-t-rex-irregularized/). I often think that the utter importance of context doesn't get enough credit. But maybe I'm just overly sensitive to it, because I decided to dive into a field where common names (definitions) have different meanings in virtually any two papers.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for the link, good read. Anyway, that reminds me of the shortest mathematician's joke: Be $\varepsilon<0$ …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $\sqsubset$ is somtimes used as a synonym for $\subset$, but this isn't universally true. For example Jech uses $\sqsubseteq$ (as in $\mathbb A \sqsubseteq \mathbb B$) to denote subalgebras of Boolean algebras. In your case, as you are interested in the meaning of $\sqsubset$ in the context of [this](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~hjafarpo/Files/MW08_CameraReady_1.pdf) paper, the meaning of $\sqsubset$ is part of Definition 1.

In general, context is key when interpreting any kind of mathematical notation. You may (but shouldn't) replace any mathematical symbol with any other without changing the meaning of a given paper - as long as you are consistent about it.

Comment: It's worthwhile adding that some symbols have a more standard meaning in the mathematical literature than others. For example, it is very, very common to use $\subset$ for the subset relation, but in my understanding the symbol $\sqsubset$ does not have any meaning that is anywhere nearly as common.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Note however that the meaning of $\subset$ varies, too; sometimes it just means subset (and proper subsets are denoted as $\subsetneq$), at other times it means proper subset (and subsets are denoted as $\subseteq$).